# Jest custom transformer - can its performance be improved?

Tags: jestjs

I'm testing the performance of a custom transformer with Jest. Currently, the transformer does nothing but return the code that it gets from Jest. The transformer has implemented the `getCacheKey` function.

Here's the entire code for the transformer:

```
function process(src, path, config, transformOptions) {
  return src;
}
exports.process = process;

function getCacheKey(fileData, filePath, configStr, options) {
  return crypto.createHash('md5')
    .update(fileData + filePath + configStr, 'utf8')
    .digest('hex');
}
exports.getCacheKey = getCacheKey;
```

[Link to the transformer](https://github.com/kulshekhar/list/blob/js/ts-transformer.js)

The jest config, in `package.json` is as follows:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/ts-transformer.js"
  },
  "testMatch": [
    "<rootDir>/test-jest/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "json"
  ]
}
```

[Link to package.json](https://github.com/kulshekhar/list/blob/js/package.json)

When testing this setup with Jest, it takes the same amount of time with and without `--no-cache` (around 9 seconds)

When testing this setup with Mocha, the first run takes around 7 seconds and subsequent runs take around 4 seconds.

In both cases (with jest and mocha), the subsequent runs were tested without changing any source or test file.

My questions:

- Shouldn't subsequent Jest runs be faster due to caching?
- Is there something in the transformer that is preventing an improvement in the testing duration?
- Is there a minimum overhead that Jest incurs which is clouding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It might be faster to update the pieces (fileData, filePath, configStr) separately so there does not have to be a copy of the file contents on the concatenation.

```
function getCacheKey(fileData, filePath, configStr, options) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
    hash.update(fileData);
    hash.update(filePath);
    hash.update(configStr);
    return hash.digest('hex');
}
```

Note:  If encoding is not provided, and the data is a string, an encoding of 'utf8' is enforced.

Comment: Doing this doesn't have any noticeable effect on the duration